# BertForNextSentencePrediction - Converting logits into boolean values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the Next Sentence Prediction model that is pre-trained in BERT.

I'm using the example in the class `TFBertForNextSequencePrediction`. I understand that the seq_relationship_score returns the logits that point out if the next sentence belongs to previous context or not. I tried with a Softmax from keras but it's not returning a boolean.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertForNextSentencePrediction

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFBertForNextSentencePrediction.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode(["My dog is called Tetley.", "My dog is my best friend"], add_special_tokens=True))[None, :]  # Batch size 1

outputs = model(input_ids)
seq_relationship_scores = outputs[0]

print(seq_relationship_scores)

import keras
print(keras.activations.softmax(seq_relationship_scores, axis=-1))
```

How can I test if two sentences have the same context with the seq_relationship_scores?

> https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.html#TFBertForNextSentencePrediction 
>   This model is a `tf.keras.Model <https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model>`__ sub-class. Use it as a regular TF 2.0 Keras Model and refer to the TF 2.0 documentation for all matter related to general usage and behavior.

Output looks something like this:

```
tf.Tensor([[ 4.642335  -3.4926772]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
Using TensorFlow backend.
tf.Tensor([[9.9970692e-01 2.9300974e-04]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert the logits to get back probabilities. Then rank the probabilities in reverse to get the nearest sentences. You don't need to use the softmax here as you're looking at similarity.